# Fading out images and replacing with another 5 and so on?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery/Javascript.

Ques: Suppose I am having 35 images and my screen size is 1200px . First time first 5 images fade In , and after few sec at same position next 5 images will fade IN and previous  one's fade-out and than next five fade-in it will do untill all images shown and when all and it do recursively.

I am getting example of one image fade In swap with another fade out But not multiple images one.

......

and so on

```
 var totalLengthphotobanner =  $('.imageClick').width()+$newPos*count;
 var $photobannerWidth = $('.photobanner').width();
 var allImage = $('img');
 var count = $( ".photobanner" ).find( allImage ).length;
 var $noOfImg;
 var $width = $('.imageClick').width();
 var $gap = 150;
 var $track =0;
 $noOfImg = Math.floor(($gap+$photobannerWidth)/($width+$gap));
 //alert($noOfImg);
 $images =1;
 $keepCount =1;
 while($keepCount<count)
    {
        var $newPos = 0;
        var $addPos = 250;
            if($track>=$noOfImg){
                for($images=1;$images<=$noOfImg;$images++){
                    $('#sponsor-'+$keepCount).css('position','absolute');
                    $('#sponsor-'+$keepCount).css('left',$newPos+'px');
                    $('#sponsor-   '+$keepCount).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
                    $newPos = $newPos+$addPos;
                    $keepCount = $keepCount+1;
                }
            }else{
                for($images=1;$images<=$track;$images++){
                    $('#sponsor-'+$keepCount).css('position','absolute');
                    $('#sponsor-'+$keepCount).css('left',$newPos+'px');
                    $('#sponsor-'+$keepCount).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
                    $newPos = $newPos+$addPos;
                    $keepCount = $keepCount+1;
                }
          }
      $track = count - $images;
    }
```

Comment: put the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to complete a simple model which I'm not sure if it's what you want.I've used recursive functions to do some **loop** work.

```js
$("#move").click(function() {
  fadeFunc();
});

function fadeFunc() {
  $(".current").fadeOut("normal", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    if ($(this).next()) {
      $(this).next().addClass("current");
      $(this).next().fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut("normal", fadeFunc);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img_group {
  width: 380px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.img {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="img_group current">
    <div class="img">Group 1</div>
    <div class="img">Group 1</div>
    <div class="img">Group 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img_group">
    <div class="img">Group 2</div>
    <div class="img">Group 2</div>
    <div class="img">Group 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img_group">
    <div class="img">Group 3</div>
    <div class="img">Group 3</div>
    <div class="img">Group 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="move">Move</button>
```

I've wrapped mutilple images into one single `<div class="img_group">`.